# Разница результатов `strcmp`

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int my_strcmp(const char* x, const char* y)
{
  int z = 0;
  do
  {
    z = ((int)*(const unsigned char*)x) - ((int)*(const unsigned char*)y);
    if (z != 0)
    {
      break;
    }
    ++x;
    ++y;
  } while (*x != '\0' && *y != '\0');
  return z;
}

typedef struct pair {
  const char* x;
  const char* y;
} pair_t;

pair_t pairs[] = {
  {"", ""},
  {"abc", ""},
  {"", "abc"},
  {"abc", "def"},
  {"def", "abc"},
  {"abc", "abc"},
  {"abc", "abd"},
  {"abd", "abc"},
  {"a", "a"},
  {NULL, NULL}
};

int main(void)
{
  pair_t* p = &pairs[0];
  while (p->x != NULL &&
         p->y != NULL)
  {
    printf(
      "'%s', '%s' = %d, %d\n",
      p->x,
      p->y,
      my_strcmp(p->x, p->y),
      strcmp(p->x, p->y));
    ++p;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Решил написать свою собственную реализацию `strcmp` (см выше). При выполнении в Linux ARM/AArch64, результаты странные:

Android Termux ARMv8l:

```
'', '' = 0, 0
'abc', '' = 97, 97
'', 'abc' = -97, -97
'abc', 'def' = -3, -3
'def', 'abc' = 3, 3
'abc', 'abc' = 0, 0
'abc', 'abd' = -1, -32
'abd', 'abc' = 1, 1
'a', 'a' = 0, 0
```

Ubuntu AArch64:

```
'', '' = 0, 0
'abc', '' = 97, 194
'', 'abc' = -97, -97
'abc', 'def' = -3, -96
'def', 'abc' = 3, 96
'abc', 'abc' = 0, 0
'abc', 'abd' = -1, -32
'abd', 'abc' = 1, 32
'a', 'a' = 0, 0
```

Но при выполнении на Kali Linux x86-64 все хорошо, вывод, такой, какой и ожидается:

```
'', '' = 0, 0
'abc', '' = 97, 97
'', 'abc' = -97, -97
'abc', 'def' = -3, -3
'def', 'abc' = 3, 3
'abc', 'abc' = 0, 0
'abc', 'abd' = -1, -1
'abd', 'abc' = 1, 1
'a', 'a' = 0, 0
```

Поясните, почему результаты отличаются?

Comment: Потому что `strcmp` в случае неравенства строк не обязана возвращать разницу между символами. Знаки совпадают - всё в порядке. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp

Comment: А посмотрите, вот такая реализация -- `int strcmp (const char *l, const char *r) { for (; *l == *r && *l; l++, r++);  return *(unsigned char *)l - *(unsigned char *)r; }` что будет возвращать на Ubuntu AArch64?

Comment: `'', '' = 0, 0`, `'abc', '' = 97, 194`, `'', 'abc' = -97, -97`, `'abc', 'def' = -3, -96`, `'def', 'abc' = 3, 96`, `'abc', 'abc' = 0, 0`,`'abc', 'abd' = -1, -32`, `'abd', 'abc' = 1, 32`,`'a', 'a' = 0, 0`

Comment: Да, интересно, что в самом деле strcmp там сравнивает. Когда сравнение не с нулем, получается разница, умноженная на 32 (справа 5 лишних нулевых бит)

Comment: @avp, https://github.com/ARM-software/optimized-routines/blob/master/string/aarch64/strcmp.S

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, Примерно это (сравнение длинных слов) я и предполагал.  Хотя алгоритм не простой, сходу не разобрал, почему результат именно такой. А вот эта тройка команд  с доступом к 2-м массивам по одному автоинкрементируемому указателю, просто шедевр, который мне как-то в голову никогда не приходил (спасибо!)-- `sub off2, src2, src1; ... ldr data2, [src1, off2]; ldr data1, [src1], 8`